# ie vertical-align:super / sub incorrect

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'd like to apply super/sub vertical alignment css attribute for a span element. After doing that, the words within the span are rendered in correct position. However, the span which contains these words looks like be placed at incorrect position(baseline position) under IE. It works fine under other browsers except for IE.

What is more interesting is I find if I assign an attribute contenteditable="true" to the span element, its position becomes correct(...).

You guys can check it here (with attribute contenteditable="true" top position is 0 and whithout attribute contenteditable="true" top position is 7):
http://jsfiddle.net/E5Af9/

You can try to remove contenteditable="true" on the first blue span to see what happen. It behaves just like what I said above.

I want to have safer options other that adding an uncertain attribute on the span element.
Does anyone have idea on it? Or does anyone can tell me whether I will have side effects in using contenteditable in span.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the problem on IE 9, even in IE 7 mode. I’m not sure of what is regarded as a problem, as the description seems to say that the words within the span are rendered correctly but the span is not—and I don’t see what that might mean.

Anyway, `vertical-align` has some quirks in browsers, and even by the specs, it may affect line height, which is often undesirable. Therefore, it is often better to use relative positioning. For example, instead of

```
vertical-align: 1ex;
```

you could set

```
position: relative; bottom: 1ex;
```

They keyword values `super` and `sub` have implementation-dependent meanings and they are often typographically unsuitable in addition to varying across browsers. The vertical placement should generally depend on the surrounding characters and on the font, so it is better to design it yourself, normally using the `em` unit or the `ex` unit, instead just telling browsers to apply their idea of superscripting or subscripting.

Comment: Thank Jukka for your detailed answer. I can reproduce this problem under IE9 & IE8. Anyway, your suggestion is really helpful. Maybe I will try to use fixed size vertical placement.

Comment: I update my example. Maybe you can check what the problem is.